# Passing function as parameter in Typescript: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to pass in this `doSomething` function into `performAction`, but the error I'm getting is `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1`

```
type someType = {
  name: string,
  id: string
}

function doSomethingFn(props: someType) {
  console.log(props.name + " " + props.id);
}

function performAction(doSomething: () => void) {
  doSomething({
    name: "foo",
    id: "bar"
  });
}

performAction(doSomethingFn);
```

Am I using the proper syntax for Typescript?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `doSomething` type seems incorrect. In the type declaration – `() => void` it takes no arguments, but later you are passing arguments to it.

For this piece of code following would work, but you would know better what should be the arguments and their types of `doSomething`. Probably use a interface if you already have an abstraction in your mind.

```
function performAction(doSomething: (stuff: { name: string, id: string }) => void) {
  doSomething({
    name: "foo",
    id: "bar"
  });
}
```

[Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20performAction(doSomething%3A%20(stuff%3A%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%2C%20id%3A%20string%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20doSomething(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%22bar%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D) for above.

Also if `string` in your code is a variable you need to change that because `string` is reserved for the type. In case you don't what to fix the type of `doSomething` right now you can use the `Function` type. [Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20performAction(doSomething%3A%20Function)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20doSomething(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%22bar%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D)

### Update

For your updated question you need to write `function performAction(doSomething: (stuff: someType) => void` [Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20someType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doSomethingFn(props%3A%20someType)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(props.name%20%2B%20%22%20%22%20%2B%20props.id)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20performAction(doSomething%3A%20(stuff%3A%20someType)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20doSomething(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%22bar%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AperformAction(doSomethingFn)%3B)

Comment: Is there any way to make it generic?

Answer (score 3):

You type doSomething as a function with no arguments: `doSomething: () => void`. Make it, dunno, `doSomething: (arg: SomeInterface) => void` (SomeInterface being, for example, `{name: string; id: string;}`).

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = 6;
let b = 2;

let res = outer(substr, a, b);
console.log(res);
res = outer(addit, a, b);
console.log(res);

function outer(inner: Function, a: number, b: number): number {
    return inner(a,b);
}

function substr(vala: number, valb: number): number {
    console.log('We are substracting');
    return vala - valb;
}

function addit(vala: number, valb: number): number {
    console.log('We are adding');
    return vala + valb;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).